# OPAM fails to publish a package - says git failed to fetch

Tags: git, opam

I am trying to publish an opam package using instructions from here:
https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html

I did create a tag and pushed it on github. 
When I try to publish it on opam with `opam publish` I get the following error message:

```
Fetching the package repository, this may take a while...
[ERROR] Uncaught exception: "/usr/bin/git fetch --multiple origin user" exited with code 128 "fatal: No such remote or remote group:
        user"
```

Do I have incorrectly set up git repository or maybe my opam installation needs some tweaks to make it work ?

Comment: Apparently it is trying to pull from a git remote called user which doesn't exists. Check your configuration where you define the remote repositories. Or try to create a new git remote called "user".

Comment: @Mickael B. I added a new remote called "user". It didn't  work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer based on the issue described here:
https://github.com/ocaml/opam-publish/issues/92

The solution is to delete folder:
`<opam root>/plugins/opam-publish/repos/ocaml%opam-repository`

*< opam root >* can be found with the command `opam config list` (look for the *root* variable in *Global opam variables* section)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps before you saw this error

```
/usr/bin/git fetch --multiple origin user" exited with code 128 "fatal: No such remote or remote group: user
```

You missed a `401 Unauthorized` error, which is something to do with a bug in a newer `github-unix` package meets GitHub deprecating an API.

Here's what I did to clean it up.

Clean up leftover opam-publish state

```
rm -rf ~/.opam/plugins/opam-publish/repos/ocaml%opam-repository
rm -f ~/.opam/plugins/opam-publish/ocaml%opam-repository.token
```

Downgrade github-unix to <4.3.0

```
opam install github-unix.4.2.0
```

Run `opam publish` again.

## References

- https://github.com/ocaml/opam-publish/issues/99
- https://github.com/ocaml/opam-publish/issues/97